# func to adapt the displayed time on a website based on the user location

Tags: html, timezone, location

i have a website available in multiple languages and i would like to know how to display the correct time zone based on the current location.

is there any function i could use or time Api?

Comment: It depends on *exactly* what you want to display.  Please give some examples.  And when you say "based on location", do you mean based on latitude and longitude from physical location?  Or do you mean based on the user's time zone settings of their computer?

Answer (score 0):

If by current location you mean the physical timezone of the user's machine, you can just use Javascript's [`Date`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object:

```js
myDiv.innerHTML = new Date().toString()
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

If by current location you mean some arbitrary language/country that the user can select, you could also use the [`Date`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object in combination with the [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) function:

```js
myDiv.innerHTML = 'Time in Jakarta: ' + new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {
  timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta'
})
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

There are a lot of functions/methods that you can use, i think the best thing to start with is to check out & experiment with what's listed in the [Date object reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).